# Error installing Ruby 2.3.0 on Yosemite via rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment, osx-yosemite

For some reason I can't get ruby 2.3.0 installed via RBENV. I got it to work with RVM though. Let me know if I need to provide further information.

Here's the error I get:

```
Downloading ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.0...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.10.5 using ruby-build 20160426)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160426211028.6622
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160426211028.6622.log

Last 10 log lines:
config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20160426211028.6622/ruby-2.3.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: You have OSX build tools installed?

Comment: Are you uninstalling rbenv when attempting to use rvm and vice versa? If not, you should, because those tools are mutually incompatible.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yeah, I only had rbenv before I decided to go with rvm. Now I have both and the rvm works fine. I was wondering why the rbenv didn't work at all. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AnthonyE yes I do. It was installed when I installed Homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your system has too strict security policy, so add `sudo` for the rbenv to give the ability to add executions. So you will like something like:

```
sudo rbenv install 2.3.0
```